# Google Chrome: URL could not be located

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, concrete5

I have a large website with many hard coded pages. If there is a broken URL Firefox doesnt seem to care. But Google Chrome and IE seem to display a horrible placeholder box (as if there should be an image in its place).

What is the best solution to scan the page of broken images? and assigning `display:none` to the image to stop the placeholder showing up?

```
function imgError(image){
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = "/images/noimage.gif";
    return true;
}

<img src="someimage.png" onerror="imgError(this);"/>
```

I found the above client side solution. But is there a way with PHP do it before the page is loaded? I am using concrete5

Comment: for a c5-specific solution, it depends on how these image tags are being generated. are they coming from a content block that's had an image added from the file manager? And then, what? You deleted the image from the file manager? Or you had "hard coded pages". Do you have a mix of .html pages on this site alongside concrete5? It all depends on what the source of these images are.

Answer (score 1):

For cases like this use the 'alt' HTML tag. This tag is used to display a description of the img in case it is not found.

```
<img src="myPath.png" alt="Here was my broken image">
```

Answer (score 0):

If images are on same server then try `file_exists` function to check if there's image. If not show something else.

Here's the code to help you:

```
if(file_exists("../img/logo.png")) {
echo '<img src="../img/logo.png" />';
} else {
 //something else
}
```